# Sidekiq Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => 'redis://192.xxx.xxx.xx:6379/0' }
end
```

In production console when I do

```
ActivationWorker.perform_async(877459)
```

It gives an error

**Redis::CannotConnectError: Error connecting to Redis on 127.0.0.1:6379 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)**

Even sidekiq.log prints

```
Booting Sidekiq 5.1.3 with redis options {:url=>"redis://192.xxx.xxx.xx:6379/0", :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-646"}
```

Comment: Is redis on the same server as rails ? if not, make sure you're allowing the connection in its configuration.

Comment: separate server @RocKhalil

Answer (score 2):

> It is important to note that to configure the location of Redis, you
>   must define both the Sidekiq.configure_server and
>   Sidekiq.configure_client blocks

[Straight from the docs](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#using-an-initializer)

So also add to your `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`:

```
Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
   config.redis = { :url => 'redis://192.xxx.xxx.xx:6379/0' }
end
```

---

Also important notes from docs:

> NOTE: The configuration hash must have symbolized keys.
>
> NOTE: Unknown parameters are passed to the underlying Redis client so
>   any parameters supported by the driver can go in the Hash.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, we know that Redis is on a separate server.

### Rails Server

Create a file in initializers: `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb`:

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: "redis://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379/12"
  }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = {
    url: "redis://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:6379/12"
  }
end
```

### Redis server

- Edit `/etc/redis/redis.conf`
- Update your binded port
- example: `bind 192.xxx.xxx.xxx`
- restart `redis`